# No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setTopFocusLevel:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get 3 errors in this block of code and really don't know how to solve them.
Maybe someone can help me.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(id)sender {

    UIImage *sourcePicture = imgView.image;
    GPUImageOutput *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageOutput alloc] init];

    CGFloat midpoint = [(UISlider *)sender value];
    [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)brightnessFilter setTopFocusLevel:midpoint - 0.1];
    [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)brightnessFilter setBottomFocusLevel:midpoint + 1];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

**1st error:**

```
`No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setTopFocusLevel:'`
```

**2nd error:**

```
`No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setBottomFocusLevel:'`
```

**3rd error:**

```
`No visible @interface 'UIImage' declares the selector 'processImage'`
```

My header:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "EAGLView.h"
#import <GPUImage.h>
#import "DMActivityInstagramPicxxr.h"
#import "GPUImageFilter.h"
#define DEG2RAD (M_PI/180.0f)

@interface GPUImageBrightnessFilter : GPUImageFilter
{
    GLint brightnessUniform;
}

@property(readwrite, nonatomic) CGFloat brightness;

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
```

Comment: UIImage doesn't have a processImage method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'll control a GPUImageBrightnessFilter via an UISlider.

Comment: How can I add the processImage method to UIImage?

Comment: You can add it using category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

This is the class of `GPUImageBrightnessFilter`:

```
#import "GPUImageFilter.h"

@interface GPUImageBrightnessFilter : GPUImageFilter
{
    GLint brightnessUniform;
}

// Brightness ranges from -1.0 to 1.0, with 0.0 as the normal level
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) CGFloat brightness; 

@end
```

The error is clear, and in other words it is saying:

What are you doing? I don't see any selector (method or property setter) with this name in the interface!

You are getting this error because not only are these methods not in `GPUImageBrightnessFilter`, they also aren't in `GPUImageFilter` (class from which `GPUImageBrightnessFilter` inherits) and not even in `GPUImageOutput` (class from which  `GPUImageFilter` inherits).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented the code but now xcode says: `Duplicate interface definition for class 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter'` and `Property has a previous declaration`

Comment: Probably you are importing (`#import`) an header file already imported from another header file that you are importing as well. Check your `#import` header. For example if you are importing `GPUImageBrightnessFilter.h` you haven't to import also `GPUImageFilter.h` because as you see above it is already imported from `GPUImageBrightnessFilter.h`

Comment: I post my header file in my question. But I don't kow what's wrong. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: ??? you imported the `GPUImageBrightnessFilter.h` and that is ok, but then why you write the interface with the property?? you have to remove all code after the imports and before `@interface ViewController ()`

Comment: Ok, I've done it (deleted the code after the imports and before the `ViewController ()`. But it's still not working (I still get the errors displayed). Can you explain me step by step what I have to do? Somehow I'm a bit confused.

Comment: you are confused because you have not clear what you are doing and why. I don't know your code and your situation. In any case i think that your `#import <GPUImage.h>` could already `#import "GPUImageFilter.h"`. So cancel from your code `#import "GPUImageFilter.h"` as well and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing. I still get the errors. Which code do you need that you can help me?

Comment: Need to know how your import and what your import headers imports. Show me the entire error from the console please.

Comment: There is nothing in the console. Xcode says only `Build Failed`.

Comment: above you mentioned an error..

Comment: 1st: `No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setTopFocusLevel:'` 2nd: `No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setBottomFocusLevel:'` 3rd:`No visible @interface 'UIImage' declares the selector 'processImage'`

Comment: But these are the initial error, i already replied to you what is the reason of these error. Don't exist and so you can't use them.